# How to stress test PouchDB

Tags: javascript, scripting, stress-testing, pouchdb

We are looking into using a CouchDB and PouchDB stack and we would like to stress test CouchDB as one of our use case can have as many as 70-80 users replicating at the same time.

We managed to stress test CouchDB and are satisfied with the result, but we would like to do some end-to-end stress test from PouchDB.

I have tried a few things:

1) Using a PhantomJS script that launches many pages in a for loop
2) Using a PhantomJS script with some kind of parallel function found on Github
3) Using a bash script and the & to launch multiple phantomJS
4) Using a bash script and GNU Parallel to launch multiple instances of PhantomJS
* all tests above are using a waitFor function to only finish when a global variable has been set to true (the only way I can think of that will wait for all the JS in the page to be executed)

While one phantomJS execution takes about 200-300ms, when running multiple, they seem be be queued somehow and we are getting numbers from 200ms to 30,000ms for the last of ~30 executions.

Looks like PhantomJS is queueing itself somehow. As I can see a steady progression of n*200ms for each subsequent requests.

I could probably build a demo app on 2-3 devices and loop PUT and Replicate, but I wanted to try to script this in a similar way that Siege can stress test a page with multiple assets. Only, I want it to "wait" until the page is really done and all the JS has finished running.

Any idea on how I could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to stress-test your entire system by simulating the load you expect to receive from users, i.e. you are not trying to test the browser performance itself. (If that's not the case, and you are trying to test in the browser, then we already have some [browser performance tests in PouchDB](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/blob/master/TESTING.md#performance-tests), although you will get bad numbers from PhantomJS because it is an old browser.)

Since PouchDB is isomorphic, I would recommend avoiding PhantomJS and just running some Node.js processes on top of LevelDB to simulate your users. PhantomJS may indeed have some queueing issues, because the underlying datastore is WebSQL, which has a global write lock. With Node, though, you can have separate processes that each represent one thread; you just have to be sure that each one has a separate LevelDB because LevelDB is not threadsafe (e.g. `new PouchDB('/tmp/some/random/directory')`).

Comment: Thanks for your help Nolan! :) You are right about PhantomJS, I'm forgetting it for this kind of testing.

We would like to mainly test the replication from PouchDB to a remote CouchDB database, because our use case can have up to 70 users at the same time and in the worst case scenario they all replicate at the same time. Conflict resolution will be fun to manage ;)

I will look into LevelDB and NodeJS, can you point me to great tutorials as I'm not familiar with LevelDB? Thanks!

Comment: No prob, just use PouchDB as you normally would inside of a Node.js script, but when you create it, point it to an empty directory and it will write the LevelDB files there: `new PouchDB('/path/to/dir')`.